# LumenでS3にファイルを移動&コピーできない

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

LumenのStorageファサードを利用してS3にファイルを移動&コピーしたいのですが、コピーができません。エラーメッセージは以下です(今回は`/var/www/html/storage/logs/lumen.log`をコピーします、ファイルは存在します)。

```
File not found at path: lumen.log
```

filesystems.phpの中身は以下です。

```
<?php
return [
    'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root'   => storage_path('logs'),
        ],
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'root'   => storage_path('logs'),
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

そして、Storageへのアクセスは以下のようにしております。

```
Storage::disk('s3')->move('lumen.log', 'storage.log');
```

ちなみに、以下はちゃんと動きましたのでアクセスの仕方が悪いわけではないと思います。

```
Storage::disk('local')->move('lumen.log', 'storage.log');
```

また、以下はS3にファイルが作成されたので、S3の設定は問題なさそうです。

```
Storage::disk('s3')->push('hogehoge');
```

composer.jsonには以下を記載しております(諸々省略)。

```
"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.5.*",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0"
```

回答をお待ちしております。

Comment: メッセージから推測するに move は S3バケット内でオブジェクトを移動するのではと思います。putしてからローカル上のファイルを削除すれば良さそうです。

Comment: なるほど…！そういう話ですか！ありがとうございます！助かりました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメント欄にあるように、以下の方法で対応を行いましたので、自己回答をいたします。

> メッセージから推測するに move は S3バケット内でオブジェクトを移動するのではと思います。putしてからローカル上のファイルを削除すれば良さそうです。